# d3 linechart plots only some points

Tags: d3.js, linechart, string-parsing, web-development-server

I am new to d3. I have about 35,000 datapoints and I am trying to plot them using linechart but the line stops after plotting some points.

I have tried reducing the number of points and starting plotting the points from index 10,000. I have attached a snip of my output for points starting from index 10,000 below here [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NfdI.jpg). I face similar issues.

Here is my python code to load the file:

```py
@app.route('/linechart')
def linechart():
    dataxls = pd.read_excel (r'/home/fortknox/Documents/PD/PD_challenge/PD_challange_dataset.xlsx') 
    df = pd.DataFrame(dataxls)
    #df.fillna(0)
    temperature = []
    consumption = []
    time = []
    for iter1, iter2 in df.iterrows():
        temperature.append(iter2.out_door_temp)
        consumption.append(iter2.electricity_usage)
        temptime = iter2.time 
        temptime = temptime.ctime()
        time.append(temptime) 
    labels = [1-05-12, 30-04-12,
27-04-12,26-04-12,
25-04-12, 24-04-12,
23-04-12,20-04-12,
19-04-12, 18-04-12,
17-04-12, 16-04-12]
    values = [0,10,9,8,2,6,4,7,8,6,4,9]
    values2 = [0,9,8,2,6,4,7,8,6,4,9,2]
    return render_template('linechart.html',temperature= temperature,consumption= consumption, time= time, title='chart',labels= labels, values= values, values2= values2)
```

Please ignore labels, values and values2. I used them to test.

Here is my d3 code:

```js
var consumption = [{% for item in consumption %}
            parseFloat("{{item}}"),
            {% endfor %}];  // convert the char to int while creating the data array

var temperature = [{% for item in temperature %}
             parseInt("{{item}}"),
            {% endfor %}];  // convert the char to int while creating the data array

var time = [{% for item in time %}
             "{{item}}",
            {% endfor %}];  // convert the char to int while creating the data array

console.log(consumption)
var labels = [{% for item in labels %}
             "{{item}}",
            {% endfor %}];  // convert the char to int while creating the data array


var data = [{% for item in values %}
             parseInt("{{item}}"),
            {% endfor %}];  // convert the char to int while creating the data array
var data2 = [{% for item in values2 %}
             parseInt("{{item}}"),
            {% endfor %}];  // convert the char to int while creating the data array

console.log("labels : "+ labels +" data : " + data + " data2 : "+ data2);
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    width = 860 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("#chart2")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
console.log(temperature);
console.log(temperature.length);
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, temperature.length])
      .range([ 0, width ]);
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
    // Add Y axis
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(temperature, function(d) { return d; })])
      .range([ height ,0 ]);
    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // Add the line
    svg.append("path")
      .datum(temperature)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", d3.line()
        .y(function(d , i) { return y(d) })
        .x(function(d , i) { return x(i) })
        )
```

The output of **console.log(temperature)** is 35181 values in console log. I have attached a snip below. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txh0S.jpg)

Here is a snip of my output:

[image: Line Plotting stops after some points]

[image: Verification of data parsing]
[image: Linechart parsing points after index 10000]

Comment: I tested your d3.js code and it seems to be working fine. It would be good to have a sample of your data or be sure that you are receiving it correctly. Here is a plunker with your code and 35000 values from 0 to 100 and it draws the whole line. https://plnkr.co/edit/N5K3oMYi1AAkj25twolp?p=preview

Comment: Hello, @GuillermoGarcia, Thank you for your response. I looked at the values from ''' console.log(temperature);
console.log(temperature.length);''', they are 35181 values in the console log.